# Get dropdown menu to lay over other items and general layout

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to build a page where the sidenav transforms into a dropdown menu. Problems are: **First:** when the dropdown menu appears, it is not centered and I can't get it to be in the center. **Second:** that the dropdown list that appears pushes the items on the bottom grid, instead of laying on top. (The container borders are for reference only)
[image of how it looks like and how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO735.png)

Here's the code for the dropdown menu (the grid container that envolves it doesn;t have margin or padding and has justify-content: center; align-items: center;) https://codepen.io/linszhz/pen/YzQYbej?editors=0100

NOTE: I've fiddled with some html and css in the past but I'm a total noob when it comes to javascript/jquery

```js
 // Dropdown Menu
        var dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
        var dropdownArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(dropdown, 0);
        dropdownArray.forEach(function (el) {
            var button = el.querySelector('a[data-toggle="dropdown"]'),
                menu = el.querySelector('.dropdown-menu'),
                arrow = button.querySelector('i.icon-arrow');

            button.onclick = function (event) {
                if (!menu.hasClass('show')) {
                    menu.classList.add('show');
                    menu.classList.remove('hide');
                    arrow.classList.add('open');
                    arrow.classList.remove('close');
                    event.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    menu.classList.remove('show');
                    menu.classList.add('hide');
                    arrow.classList.remove('open');
                    arrow.classList.add('close');
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            };
        })

        Element.prototype.hasClass = function (className) {
            return this.className && new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)").test(this.className);
        };
```

```css
      .container {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 10px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .container>ul {
            list-style: none;
            position: relative;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0 0 20px 0;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            
        }


        .dropdown a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"] {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            border: solid 2px black;
            margin: 0;
            outline: 0;
            font-size: 1em;
            text-decoration: none;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"] {
            border-color: #000000;
            background: #ffffff;
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px 0;
            font-weight: bold;
        }


        .dropdown .icon-arrow {
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            font-size: 1.4em;
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            top: 0px;
            right: 10px;
        }

        .dropdown .icon-arrow.open {
            bottom: 0px;
            transform: rotate(-180deg);
            transition: transform 0.4s;
        }

        .dropdown .icon-arrow.close {
            bottom: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            transition: transform 0.4s;
        }

        .dropdown .icon-arrow:before {
            content: '⌄';
        }

        .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
            max-height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            border: solid 2px black;
            
        }

        .dropdown .dropdown-menu li {
            padding: 0;
        }

        .dropdown .dropdown-menu li a {
            display: block;
            color: #000000;
            background: #ffffff;
            padding: 5px 0;
        }

        .dropdown .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }

        .dropdown .show {
            display: block;
            max-height: 600px;
            animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
            transition:  1s ease-in-out;
        }

        .dropdown .hide {
            max-height: 0;
            animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
            transition:  0.6s ease-out;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="sidenav-dropdown">

        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">FAQ <i class="icon-arrow"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li> <a href="#home">About us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">Track your order</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">Shipping & Handling</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">Refund & Return</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">Terms of Service</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">Contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sequi dignissimos ex aut excepturi inventore quam sed, dolor cumque consectetur a, adipisci pariatur illo! Numquam fugit sunt ad doloremque reprehenderit expedita.\</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the div overlay another one, I just added the code below in the CSS and that worked.

.container class (Removed the overflow so it can overlay)

```
/*overflow: hidden;*/
```

.show and .hide classes

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
width:100%;
```

```js
// Dropdown Menu
        var dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
        var dropdownArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(dropdown, 0);
        dropdownArray.forEach(function (el) {
            var button = el.querySelector('a[data-toggle="dropdown"]'),
                menu = el.querySelector('.dropdown-menu'),
                arrow = button.querySelector('i.icon-arrow');

            button.onclick = function (event) {
                if (!menu.hasClass('show')) {
                    menu.classList.add('show');
                    menu.classList.remove('hide');
                    arrow.classList.add('open');
                    arrow.classList.remove('close');
                    event.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    menu.classList.remove('show');
                    menu.classList.add('hide');
                    arrow.classList.remove('open');
                    arrow.classList.add('close');
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            };
        })

        Element.prototype.hasClass = function (className) {
            return this.className && new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)").test(this.className);
        };
```

```css
      .container {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 10px;
            position: relative;
            /*overflow: hidden;*/
        }

        .container>ul {
            list-style: none;
            position: relative;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0 0 20px 0;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            
        }

        .dropdown a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"] {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            border: solid 2px black;
            margin: 0;
            outline: 0;
            font-size: 1em;
            text-decoration: none;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"] {
            border-color: #000000;
            background: #ffffff;
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px 0;
            font-weight: bold;
        }


        .dropdown .icon-arrow {
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            font-size: 1.4em;
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            top: 0px;
            right: 10px;
        }

        .dropdown .icon-arrow.open {
            bottom: 0px;
            transform: rotate(-180deg);
            transition: transform 0.4s;
        }

        .dropdown .icon-arrow.close {
            bottom: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            transition: transform 0.4s;
        }

        .dropdown .icon-arrow:before {
            content: '⌄';
        }

        .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
            max-height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            border: solid 2px black;
            
        }

        .dropdown .dropdown-menu li {
            padding: 0;
        }

        .dropdown .dropdown-menu li a {
            display: block;
            color: #000000;
            background: #ffffff;
            padding: 5px 0;
        }

        .dropdown .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }

        .dropdown .show {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            width:100%;
            display: block;
            max-height: 600px;
            animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
            transition:  1s ease-in-out;
        }

        .dropdown .hide {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            width:100%;
            max-height: 0;
            animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
            transition:  0.6s ease-out;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="sidenav-dropdown">

        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">FAQ <i class="icon-arrow"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li> <a href="#home">About us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">Track your order</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">Shipping & Handling</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">Refund & Return</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">Terms of Service</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">Contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sequi dignissimos ex aut excepturi inventore quam sed, dolor cumque consectetur a, adipisci pariatur illo! Numquam fugit sunt ad doloremque reprehenderit expedita.\</div>
```

About the centered menu, I have tried it out but here it's working fine.

Comment: Thank you! Really did solve the dropdown problem (although for some reason I can't manage to make the list content be the same size of the menu container. It is just slightly bigger and in 99% it is slightly smaller lol. For the centering, here's the code of how it looks https://codepen.io/linszhz/pen/YzQYbej?editors=0100